# 'heapdumponoutofmemory' occurs during data transfer using logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I'm using Logstash to extract data from Database and send data to Elasticsearch.
Everything works fine; data is well processed and sent to Elasticsearch without loss.

The problem, however, is burden on the server.
I'm running four logstash.conf files on AWS ec2 instance.
I checked process viewer and found out that logstash files are eating too much memory.
Please refer to following screenshot.

---

[UPDATED Feb, 27]
I've also attached the screenshot with the result of `jvmtop` command.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/29wHc.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gmoc5.png)

Comment: How big is your server have? Then see [docs here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/heap-sizing.html), which say: `The default installation of Elasticsearch is configured with a 1 GB heap. For just about every deployment, this number is usually too small. If you are using the default heap values, your cluster is probably configured incorrectly.` Have you tried adjusting your heap size limit?

Comment: Thanks for the comment @samiles

I'm currently running logstash on test server with the memory size of 4GB. I've set Xms and Xmx to, respectively, 256m and 1g for the logstash.